# How to Integrate react-native to iOS with separate folders. (Not inside react root directory).?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, node-modules

I already have a project on iOS and Android. I would like to implement some new features in react-native. I have done integration in sample apps as well and its working like a charm.

But my doubt is, this is working when I have iOS and Android code in react root directory. when I move the iOS and Android in a separate folder unable to install pod in ios. Getting error in "use_native_modules".

Working Folder Structure

[image: working_folder_structure]

But I need

[image: Expecting_folder_structure]

I have changed the path in Podfile pointing to the react directory. When I use

```
require_relative '../ReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules
use_native_modules!
```

I am unable to install the pods. getting

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] /usr/local/bin/node -e try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'
Require stack:
- /Users/user/Documents/Sample ReactNative Projects/SeperateFolders/iOS/[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at [eval]:1:87
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:131:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:295:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:98:25) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/user/Documents/Sample ReactNative Projects/SeperateFolders/iOS/[eval]'
  ]
}
.

 #  from /Users/user/Documents/Sample ReactNative Projects/SeperateFolders/iOS/Podfile:48
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    
 >    use_native_modules!
 #    
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Also when I comment those 2 lines in pod file auto-linked pods are not getting installed.
Is there any way to achieve this?
or Is this the structure we need to follow?

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Prakash, any luck, I am facing same issue while upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing `pod install` in **React** directory with flag `--project-directory`

In your case based on provided image of directory structure.

```sh
cd React/
pod install --project-directory=../iOS
```